# Received fatal alert: protocol_version and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, maven-3, spring-cloud

I'm learning from git projects:"https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-zookeeper",when i import the project into intellij idea IDE,and run mvn --settings .settings.xml package in terminal,it shows error :

```
spring-cloud-zookeeper-master>mvn --settings .settings.xml package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-build/3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-build:3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to spring-snapshots (https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapsho
t-local): Received fatal alert: protocol_version
Downloading: https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-build/3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-cloud-build-3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-zookeeper:3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (D:\projects\study\spring-cloud-zookeeper-master\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-build:pom:3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT from/to spring-snapshots (https://repo.spring.i
o/libs-snapshot-local): Received fatal alert: protocol_version and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 14, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?  (I am getting the same error with a vanilla SpringBoot application).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to activate Use plugin registry.

[image: using plugin registry]